# Move sidekiq job straight to dead queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

Is it possible to move sidekiq job straight to dead queue from SidekiqWorker instance level (i.e. while executing)

```
class MyWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: 9

  def perform(name)
    if name == 'StackOverflow'
      # ----> skip_retry_queue_and_go_to_dead_queue
    else 
      # do_stuff!
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Not dynamically within an executing job.

Statically, if you set `sidekiq_options retry: 0`, the job will go straight to the Dead set if it raises an error.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling#configuration

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: 9

  def perform(name)
    if name == 'StackOverflow'
      :kill
    else 
      # do_stuff!
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**