# How to put a job to Dead using Sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

Is it possible, when catching an error in a job, to put this job in dead?

Something like:

```
class MyJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default
  sidekiq_options retry: 5

  rescue_from MyError do
    # This is where I have to put the job in dead.
  end

  def perform(document)
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: If your intention is to just stop the job from retrying ... why not just return true and allow it to be marked as complete?

Comment: @Jon For these errors, I need to put the job in dead so that it can be tracked there. I also need to notify the support about all jobs from dead.

Comment: Then I'd recommend using something like sentry.io to do this rather than manually monitoring the dead queue. You can configure `death_handlers` to handle this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956493/move-sidekiq-job-straight-to-dead-queue) ... you cannot dynamically do this within your job. Your best option would be to set the retries to zero.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling#configuration) ... Skip retries, send a failed job straight to the Dead set:

```
class NonRetryableWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: 0

  def perform(...)
  end
end
```